# HBASE mutateRows PHP example

Tags: php, hbase, thrift

I want to mutate(Update) an array of rows in HBase table using php. One of the options is looping through each rowKey and use the '**mutateRow**' thrift method. This approach is time and resource consuming.

I discovered that there is a '**mutateRows**' method in the php thrift API but it is not documented at all. I want to know how is each rowKey mutation passed since '**mutateRows**' accepts the following arguments '**mutateRows($tableName, array $rowBatches, array $attributes)**'

Thank you.

Comment: IIRC there are two versions of the HBASE API. Make sure you pick the right one.

Comment: I am using thrift api v1. @JensG